# Constant rank for an analytic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Given a singular $n\times n$ matrix whose coefficients are analytic functions of a single variable in a neighbourhood of 0, I need to prove that there is an integer $r$, $1\leq r\leq n$ such that there is a $r\times r$ submatrix whose determinant is not identically zero but every $r+1\times r+1$ submatrix is singular.

I know that the rank of a matrix is a lower semicontinuous function of its coefficients, but this does not seem to help. Some hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this matrix guaranteed to be singular for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$? Also, is this $r$ required to be the same for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: No, I will make changes. The matrix is analytic only in a neighbourhood of zero.

Answer (score 0):

I may be underestimating the question, but these are my hints.

1. The claim is clearly true when you freeze the coefficients, say, at $z=0$.
2. The rank is $n-k$, where $k$ is the dimension of the null space, that is, the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$. Also, the other $n-k$ eigenvalues are bounded away from $0$.
3. Rouche's theorem guarantees that the number of roots of analytic functions (in particular, polynomial) in a certain region does not change if the perturbation of the polynomial is "small" (in a particular sense).